# How to trigger a jQuery function on future elements

Tags: jquery

I have a page where some tweets are dynamically fetched from Twitter. It's like a news ticker thing. The whole page is over here http://jsfiddle.net/R6D4R/.

The page works in jsfiddle because the content is already in there, whereas the content on the live site is dynamically placed into the divs. The ticker() function still works, but the if statement is not taking effect. Could anyone help me fix this?

EDIT:

Sorry guys, I didn't clarify why the if statement is there for. The function works on its own, but I don't want the function to run when there's only one tweet. That's why I have `if (tickerli.length != 1)`. I should probably use > 1 instead of != 1, but you get the idea

Comment: How is the content being placed into the divs?  Are you able to modify the code that is dynamically adding content?

Comment: I can actually modify the code, but I prefer not to because it takes too much work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, completely redoing my answer as I was confused about what you were asking:

To deal with dynamically added elements in your `ticker()` function, you have to re-evaluate your selector on each call of the function like this:

```
$(function(){
    function ticker() {
        var tickerLi = $('.tweet_list li');
        if (tickerLi.length > 1) {
            tickerLi.first().fadeOut(function() {
               $(this).appendTo($('.tweet_list')).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    }

    setInterval(ticker, 2000);
}
```

---

This was the previous answer when I thought you wanted help with event handling on dynamically added elements.

To install event handlers that will work on elements that are added dynamically in the future, you need to use delegated event handling.  To do, you can use:

```
$(static parent selector).on(event, selector of dynamic element, fn);
```

Note: there are two forms of `.on()`, one is static and one is dymamic (uses delegated event handling).  To use dynamic event handling, you bind the `.on()` handler to a parent element that is not dynamic and then you pass (as the 2nd argument to `.on()`, a selector that matches the dynamic element).

In your jsFiddle for a click handler on the tweet text, that would work like this:

```
$('twitter-container-34').on('click', '.tweet_text', function() {
    // your event handling code here
});
```

Note: jQuery `.on()` was added in jQuery v1.7.  For earlier versions of jQuery, use `.delegate()`.

Comment: The tweets are actually not intended to be clicked on. It just kinda runs on its own. It's a ticker, nothing special. It displays tweets and doesn't interact with users

Comment: @user14412 - so what is your question then?  What are you trying to do to the newly added tweets?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/R6D4R/ in the js, it says `if (tickerli.length != 1)` if you change it too == 1 instead of != 1, you can then see what it does

Comment: @user14412 - OK, I've redone my answer now that I have a better idea what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

That's the ticket!! Delegate has saved my life on more than one occasion.

Comment: How do you use delegate on a custom function with has nothing to do with mouse events and all that (interactions)?